# Excluding less-loader from webpack bundles

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, less

I'm using Webpack to compile my JavaScript bundles and am very happy with it. I'm also using it to compile my LESS files to CSS via the `ExtractTextPlugin` which is also working really well. I've started looking into the end size of the bundle and it's makeup and have found something I'd like to fix:

[image: Bundle size breakdown]

`less-loader` is taking up 9.9% of the bundle size. That seems a lot in and of itself, however what really strikes me is that I don't think I really need it in the bundle at all. I've already extracted the CSS as it's own file and don't do any `require('./component.less')` anywhere in my JavaScript modules.

Is there a way of asking webpack to exclude it that won't ruin the `less` -> `css` compilation?

Answer (score 2):

With [`ExtractTextPlugin`](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin#extract-text-plugin-for-webpack-2), your built style sources do not become a part of the resulting JS bundle. They'll rest in the output directory and unless you explicitly reference the files, they will not be included in the document.

I'm assuming the tool for analysis that you're using includes all outputs of the compilation as being part of "the bundle".

Answer (score 0):

It seems an error in webpack-visualizer.

Open node_modules/less-loader -> index.js, take any string from it (I use `loaderUtils.parseQuery`) and search for it in your bundle.

I found nothing, so seems loader not included.